# Java runtime exception - "java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
at ShoppingCartManager.printMenu(ShoppingCartManager.java:24)
at ShoppingCartManager.main(ShoppingCartManager.java:15)
```

My code issue seems to be in line 24 and 15 of my codes and I spend hours trying to fix it please help.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Customer's Name:");
  String customerName = scnr.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter Today's Date:");
  String currentDate = scnr.nextLine();
  ShoppingCart shopCart = new ShoppingCart(customerName, currentDate);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Customer Name: "+ shopCart.getCustomerName());
  System.out.println("Today's Date: "+ currentDate);
  System.out.println("");
  printMenu(shopCart); // LINE 15

  }

  public static void printMenu(ShoppingCart shopCart) {
  while(true) {
     System.out.println("MENU\na - Add item to cart\nd - Remove item from 
     cart\nc - Change item quantity\ni - Output items' descriptions\no -
     Output  shopping cart\nq - Quit\n\nChoose an option:");
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
     char ch = scnr.next().charAt(0); // LINE 24
     scnr.nextLine();
     if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' ) {
        System.out.println("ADD ITEM TO CART");
        System.out.println("Enter Item Name: ");
        String name = scnr.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Item Description: ");
        String itemDescritpion = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Item Price: ");
        int itemPrice = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Item Quantity: ");
        int quantity = scnr.nextInt();
        scnr.nextLine();
        ItemToPurchase item = new ItemToPurchase(name, itemDescritpion,itemPrice, quantity);
        shopCart.addItem(item);
     }
```

This is a OnlineShoppingCart problem and it works on eclipse but doesnt work on the online website that I'm trying to submit to. I tried converting the char ch = scnr.next().charAt(0); scnr.nextLine(); to String a = sncr.nextLine(); char ch = a.charAt(0); but that doesnt work either and still gives me the same error at the start.

Comment: What is the defined input of the problem. Perhaps you misunderstood what the input is, and since we don't know what it's supposed to be, it's impossible for us to identify the issue.

Comment: try `char ch = scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);` and check

Comment: I think the problem is liable to be the nature of `System.in`. You define a `Scanner` instance to read from `System.in`; on your own IDE, `System.in` is liable to be your console or something similar, but for the online environment, I don't know what it would be. `Scanner` blocks waiting for input; if it's throwing this exception, it means it cannot wait, and that suggests that the environment expects input from somewhere that isn't going to give any. So figure otu where the input is supposed to be coming from.